# Join together sentences from parsed pdf

Tags: python, join, indexing, pdf-parsing

I have some text scraped from pdfs and I have parsed out the text and currently have everything as strings in a list. I would like to join together sentences that were returned as separate strings because of breaks on the pdf page. For example,

```
list = ['I am a ', 'sentence.', 'Please join me toge-', 'ther. Thanks for your help.']
```

I would like to have:

```
list = ['I am a sentence.', 'Please join me together. Thanks for your help.']
```

I currently have the following code which joins some sentences but the second sub sentence that joined to the first is still returned. I am aware this is due to indexing but am not sure how to fix the issue.

```
new = []

def cleanlist(dictlist):
    for i in range(len(dictlist)):

    if i>0:

        if dictlist[i-1][-1:] != ('.') or dictlist[i-1][-1:] != ('. '):
            new.append(dictlist[i-1]+dictlist[i])

        elif dictlist[i-1][-1:] == '-':
            new.append(dictlist[i-1]+dictlist[i])

        else:
            new.append[dict_list[i]]
```

Comment: Why do you want the last two sentences to be joined together, and not separate entries in your list?

Comment: This was just a simplified example, but the reason is that I want to retain paragraph structures from the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generator approach:

```
def cleanlist(dictlist):
    current = []
    for line in dictlist:
        if line.endswith("-"):
            current.append(line[:-1])
        elif line.endswith(" "):
            current.append(line)
        else:
            current.append(line)
            yield "".join(current)
            current = []
```

Use it like this:

```
dictlist = ['I am a ', 'sentence.', 'Please join me toge-', 'ther. Thanks for your help.']
print(list(cleanlist(dictlist)))
# ['I am a sentence.', 'Please join me together. Thanks for your help.']
```

Comment: This works but could you explain the lines under the else statement?

Comment: @SusanChen: If you are confused by the `yield`, you should look up [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). It basically hands this value to the outside. And [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) joins an iterable using a string (here the empty string, so it is just a concatenation).